# ALTER SEQUENCE to use schema?

Tags: postgresql, schema

Consider tables `cats` and `dogs` in `ani` animals schema.

During sequences creation, sequence for cats.id **used schema**, whereas sequence for dogs.id **didn't use schema**:

```
create sequence ani.cats_id_seq
create sequence dogs_id_seq
```

How can I modify the `dogs_id_seq` so it also uses schema?

For example: `ALTER SEQUENCE dogs_id_seq RENAME TO ani.dogs_id_seq` this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html):

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dogs_id_seq SET SCHEMA ani;
```

Comment: Thanks. P.S. Would anyone share opinion whether it's better to use sequences with or without schemas, please?

Comment: There are no sequences without schema. Perhaps you were creating it in the `public` schema. I'd always keep the sequences in the same schema as the tables they are used with.